# Datastax DevCenter Application launching with an error "An error occured , see the log file null"

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-startup, windows-dev-center

I am using DevCenter of Datastax to connect CassandraDB for few months.

Today suddenly it started throwing an error "An error occured , see the log file null" while launching the tool/app, but actually no error/error log file saved for reference.

I tried running Repair tool , still same issue facing.
I tried delete and install it again , still facing same issue.

I guess something courrpted in eclipse relates stuff of DevCenter but not sure.

Can any boday help on this please. how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier i was using java1.8 , it was working fine. Now I updated my java version to Java 17 , so this not launching and giving error.
Even latest version DevCenter for windows64 is not working.

So I switched back to Java1.8 now it is working.